# angularjs directive don't work (node.js and angularjs newbee)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive

i'm learning AngularJS and Node.js. I'm trying to build a small website ("hello website"), but i have a problem with angularjs directive (i guess). This is my project structure

root
 + angularFiles
------ angularMenu.js 
 + templates 
------ menu.html 
- index.html 
- servidor.js

as you can see, nothing special...
the code of files:

```
servidor.js (web server)

    var port=9000;

    //importamos librerias etc...
    var express= require('express');

    var app=express();

    app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/'));

    //rutas para las peticiones
    app.get('/',function(req,res)
    {
        res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
        console.log("index");
    });

    app.listen(port);

    console.log("servidor lanzado y escuchando en puerto "+port);
```

the web server works

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>
    <head>
        <title>Colonias canguesas</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!--css bootstrap-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--carga de scripts-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script src="angularFiles/angularMenu.js"></script>

        <div id="Wrapper">
            <div id="navegacion" ng-app="menuApp">
                <menuTemplate></menuTemplate>
            </div>

            <div id="cuerpo">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

it's a normal index

```
menu.html

<nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top'>
<section ng-init="tab=1" class='container'>
    <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
        <!--<li ng-repeat="tabs in items.menu" ng-class="{active:tab === $index}"><a href ng-click="tab = $index">{{tabs}}</a></li>-->
        <li ng-class="{active:tab===1}"><a href ng-click="tab = 1">Informaci&oacute;n &nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab===2}"><a href ng-click="tab = 2">Fotos &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-picture'></i></a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab===3}"><a href ng-click="tab = 3">Listado de gatos &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></i></a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab===4}"><a href ng-click="tab = 4">Cont&aacute;ctanos &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></i></a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab===5}"><a href ng-click="tab = 5">Puntos de recogida &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker'></i></a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab===6}"><a href ng-click="tab = 6">Entidades colaboradoras &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-gift'></i></a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab===7}"><a href ng-click="tab = 7">Mercadillo &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-euro'></i></a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab===8}"><a href ng-click="tab = 8">Log in &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></i></a></li>
    </ul>
```

it's the template i want use to navigate

```
angularMenu.js



var menuApp=angular.module("menuApp",[]);

menuApp.config(function($logProvider)
{
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
})

    //directivas
.directive("menuTemplate",function()
{
    return{
            restrict:'E',
            templateUrl:'templates/menu.html',
            replace: true
          };
});
```

the angular menu file.

Everything seems ok but when i use the directive to insert my menu template, it doesn't work, i only have a white page. The server is working without problems... where is the error? why my directive don't shows the menu template?.

i've tryed a lot of things, changed routes of my templateUrl directive, etc...and didn't worked for me. I did a controller that worked correctly but not the directive.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two small problems.  The first is the one that's causing the main issue.

When you write a directive in AngularJS you have to use camelCase in your javascript but spinal-case in your html.

So in your directive, you've got it correctly named as: `menuTemplate` but in your html, you need to change it to:

```
<menu-template></menu-template>
```

Also, in your template, make sure you don't forget to close your section and nav tags.

```js
var menuApp=angular.module("menuApp",[]);

menuApp.config(function($logProvider)
{
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
})   //directivas
.directive("menuTemplate",function()
{
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:'templates/menu.html',
    replace: true
  };
});
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

```html
  <!--carga de scripts-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js'></script>
  <script src="angularMenu.js"></script>
  
  <div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="navegacion" ng-app="menuApp">
      <menu-template></menu-template>


      <!-- Below is your template -->
      <!-- I'm using the template cache so that I can 'fake' -->
      <!-- your file structure, since I can't reproduce it in -->
      <!-- the snippet environment. -->
      
      <!-- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache -->
      
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/menu.html">
        <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top'>
          <section ng-init="tab=1" class='container'>
            <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
              <!--<li ng-repeat="tabs in items.menu" ng-class="{active:tab === $index}"><a href ng-click="tab = $index">{{tabs}}</a></li>-->
              <li ng-class="{active:tab===1}"><a href ng-click="tab = 1">Informaci&oacute;n &nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a></li>
              <li ng-class="{active:tab===2}"><a href ng-click="tab = 2">Fotos &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-picture'></i></a></li>
              <li ng-class="{active:tab===3}"><a href ng-click="tab = 3">Listado de gatos &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></i></a></li>
              <li ng-class="{active:tab===4}"><a href ng-click="tab = 4">Cont&aacute;ctanos &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></i></a></li>
              <li ng-class="{active:tab===5}"><a href ng-click="tab = 5">Puntos de recogida &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker'></i></a></li>
              <li ng-class="{active:tab===6}"><a href ng-click="tab = 6">Entidades colaboradoras &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-gift'></i></a></li>
              <li ng-class="{active:tab===7}"><a href ng-click="tab = 7">Mercadillo &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-euro'></i></a></li>
              <li ng-class="{active:tab===8}"><a href ng-click="tab = 8">Log in &nbsp;<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </nav>      
      </script>
      
      
    </div>

    <div id="cuerpo"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! it was driving me crazy! those kind of errors are the one that you'll never forguet in your life =)

Comment: Yes, that one especially because there's no error in the console.  Best of luck!